# Dockerising Laravel Project Database connection issue

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

Hi I am dockerising my laravel project but at the last stage I got an error while running below command

```
sudo docker-compose up
```

Below is the log for above command

```
db_1   | Version: '5.7.33'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL 
Community Server (GPL)
app_1  | 
app_1  |    Illuminate\Database\QueryException 
app_1  | 
app_1  |   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from 
information_schema.tables where table_schema = foomotion_website and table_name = migrations 
and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
app_1  | 
app_1  |   at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:671
app_1  |     667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll 
format the error
app_1  |     668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this 
exception a
app_1  |     669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the 
database's errors.
app_1  |     670|         catch (Exception $e) {
app_1  |   > 671|             throw new QueryException(
app_1  |     672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
app_1  |     673|             );
app_1  |     674|         }
app_1  |     675|
app_1  | 
app_1  |       +35 vendor frames 
app_1  |   36  artisan:37
app_1  |
```

Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
foomotionwebsite_app_1 exited with code 1

It might be a port conflict or any command error

Here is my Docke file

```
FROM php:7
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openssl zip unzip git
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --        
filename=composer
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  libfreetype6-dev \
  libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
  libmcrypt-dev \
  libpng-dev \
  && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv \
  && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
  && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
COPY --from=mlocati/php-extension-installer /usr/bin/install-php-extensions /usr/bin/
RUN install-php-extensions zip
RUN composer install
CMD php artisan db:create
CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8181
EXPOSE 8181
```

and here is docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
   build: .
   ports:
    - "8009:8000"
  volumes:
    - .:/app
env_file: .env.docker
working_dir: /app
command: bash -c 'php artisan migrate && php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0'
depends_on:
  - db
links:
  - db
db:
   image: "mysql:5.7"
  environment:
  - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=
  - MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb
  - MYSQL_USER=root
  - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mypassword
volumes:
  - /home/dockers/data/:/var/lib/mysql
ports:
  - "3307:3306"
```

and here is .env.docker file

```
APP_NAME=Foomotion
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:HHUfXDkDt5NXH0wIL7smFDRHc3Rg7pNBRn1xfRQFb0I=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=localhost
LOG_CHANNEL=stack
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3307
DB_DATABASE=mydb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=mypassword
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
#MAIL_MAILER=
#MAIL_HOST=
#MAIL_PORT=
#MAIL_USERNAME=
#MAIL_PASSWORD=
#MAIL_ENCRYPTION=
#MAIL_FROM_NAME=
#MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=
#MAIL_MAILER=smtp
#MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
#MAIL_PORT=587
#MAIL_USERNAME=apikey
#MAIL_PASSWORD=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
#MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
#MAIL_FROM_NAME="Emet Taz"
#MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="emett@foomotionmail.com"
#MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
#MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
#MAIL_PORT=587
#MAIL_USERNAME=muzammilismail8@gmail.com
#MAIL_PASSWORD="gjekawavwcxrputw"
#MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
#MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=muzammilismail8@gmail.com
#MAIL_PORT=2525
#MAIL_USERNAME=null
#MAIL_PASSWORD=null
#MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same error and solved the problem by changing the DB_HOST field in the .env file.
You can access the container and IP addresses with the command below. You can solve the problem by typing your container IP running for mysql into the DB_HOST field.

```
docker inspect -f '{{.Name}} - {{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' $(docker ps -aq)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
/mysql - 172.18.0.4
/nginx - 172.18.0.2
/php - 172.18.0.3
```

Comment: though giving IP works.... but its unnecessary because you make it work by giving the container name directly LIke DB_HOST=db

Answer (score 0):

docker inspect -f '{{.Name}} - {{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' $(docker ps -aq)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue using these environments param in my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD="yes"
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${$DB_DATABASE}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
```

keep in mind to set properly your `.env` variables.